# python replaces single backlash with double when using extend

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, for-loop, extend

The below code is extending the list but inserting double backslashes "\\".

How do i get it to only extend to the list with one backslash "\"?

```
x =["env1","env2","env3"]
j=[]

for env in x:
    q="\\\\servername\path"+env+"\path"
    w="\\\\servername\path"+env+"\path"
    j.extend((q,w))

print j  # ['\\\\\\\servername\\\pathenv1\\\\path',...]
```

I have tried converting it to a raw string but still get the same problem:

```
x =["env1","env2","env3"]
j=[]

for env in x:
    q=r"\servername\path"+env+"\path"
    w=r"\\servername\path"+env+"\path"
    j.extend((q,w))

print j  # [\\\servername\\\path\\\path', '\\\\\\\servername\\\\path\\\path',...]
```

Comment: what are you trying to do? maybe you should use `os.path.join()`?

Comment: i want the output to be \\\\servername\path\path and then extend it to list 'j'

Comment: @TomMart Just use `os.path.join()` as @Chris suggested. `extend` has nothing to do with your problem which is not a real problem to begin with because the addition of the extra slashes does not corrupt the paths.

Comment: I understand now thanks